# Why calling methods from container class instead of instances of it in Java

Tags: java, class, methods, collections, call

I am trying to learn java collections. But there is a particular syntax that i can't understand about calling collection methods. Like `.toString()` or `.sort()`
e. g. ;

I don't understand the reason why we are calling the below methods from Arrays class or Collections class. For printing arrays this is called inside a `println()`.

```
Arrays.toString(myArray);
```

For sorting lists

```
Collections.sort(myList);
```

And why not ?

```
myArray.toString();

myList.sort();
```

Can any one walk me through it?

Comment: toString and sort are static methods in Arrays and Collections class which take a parameter, so I don't see any reason to change it to the syntax you want

Comment: You are basically asking "why are the APIs designed like that instead of like this?", which can only be answered by the people who designed the APIs. Also note that `ArrayList` _does_ have a `sort` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the first line of the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/index.html):

> The collections framework is a unified architecture for representing and manipulating collections, enabling them to be manipulated independently of the details of their representation. It reduces programming effort while increasing performance. It enables interoperability among unrelated APIs, reduces effort in designing and learning new APIs, and fosters software reuse. The framework is based on more than a dozen collection interfaces. It includes implementations of these interfaces and algorithms to manipulate them.

The objective is to reduce code duplication. In the case of `myList.sort()`, all implementations of the `List` interface would have to implement the `sort` function, and each implementation's sort may vary in behaviour. But as a static method on the `Collections` class, `List` implementations do not need to implement the sort function. From a user's perspective, you can pass whatever `List` you have to `Collections.sort()` and know what is going to happen.

Since Java 8, this functionality could have been implemented with default methods, which is what [`List.sort(comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) does. Default methods allow all implementations an interface to receive the implementation defined in the interface, so from Java 8 it *is* possible to do do `myList.sort()`, with the caveat that you have to tell it how to sort by providing a comparison function. For example, assuming you have a `List<Integer>`: `mylist.sort(Integer::compareTo)`. But the Collections Framework pre-dates default methods, hence the need for `Collections.sort()`.

As well as `Collections.sort()` and `List.sort(comparator)`, you can also use `Stream.sorted()`: `myList.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 3):

The reasons are different for your two examples:

There's no custom implementation of `toString` in array types. For `MyType[].toString()`, the developer doesn't get to "override" `toString()` for the array type. This is why the helper `Arrays.toString` is provided. The `toString` implementation on array types is the one inherited from `Object`, which is almost always not very helpful.

`List.sort` is a `default` method in `List`, introduced with Java 8. Before then, it was possible to sort only by using `Collections.sort`. If you look at the source of `Collections.sort`, it delegates the sorting itself to `List.sort`. As for why this was not in `List` from the beginning, that can only be answered by the API designers. One reason I can think of, though, is consistency (`Collections` has a number of static collections methods, and Java didn't support static methods in interfaces until version 8).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call these static methods directly on the object as the arguments won't match. The methods are bound to the class not to a specific instance of it so you have to give the object as an argument. Also, the methods do different things:

```
Arrays.toString(myArray);
```

is a convinience method to print the content of an array. If you call `myArray.toString()` the hashcode of the object is printed.

Comment: check and test your first sentence then correct it. it does not mean that you can not call static methods using a class's objects, although static methods are bounded to classes.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use

```
Arrays.toString(myArray);
```

instead of

```
myArray.toString();
```

Because, if the myArray will be null, then myArray.toString() will throw java.lang.NullPointerException but Arrays.toString(myArray) will return null. Same as with myArray.sort()

Answer (score 0):

Java's `toString()` for an array is to print `[`, followed by a character representing the *type of the array's elements* , followed by `@` then the "**identity hash code**" of the array (think of it like you would a "memory address").

To get something meaningful in human understandable you need `Arrays.toString(myArray);`

> Arrays don't override `toString`, There's a static method:
>   `java.util.Arrays.toString` to rescue.